# Stop this async function calls, just return simple values instead

Tags: c#, async-await

I simply want to return a string from a function where I need to do api calls on windows phone environment. I dont want to return a Task, just a string.

I simply dont know how to get values from functions without always using await at the exact place I call a function that should be simply executed (which makes this entire async/await thing senseless).

Please explain me how I can get something like this:

```
string TheStringIWant(someParameter)
{
 string result = await LoadDataAsync();
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm going to give you the "hard love" answer.

> I simply want to return a string from a function where I need to do api calls on windows phone environment. I dont want to return a Task, just a string.

Too bad. The *correct* solution is to return a `Task<string>`, ***especially*** on a mobile platform. Any other solution is just going to be a hack.

> I simply dont know how to get values from functions without always using await at the exact place I call a function that should be simply executed (which makes this entire async/await thing senseless).

It's not senseless at all. `async`/`await` is what keeps your UI responsive. This is *necessary* for your app to be accepted in the Windows Store.

Comment: Thanks for the hard love, I like that :) So what happens when I call an async function and have the await keyword right in front of it, as long the function needs to return something, the ui thread keeps running and updating the ui?

Comment: @Ravior: Generally, yes. The thread is free to do other things (like responding to user input) when it does an `await`. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post you may find helpful.

Comment: This is an extraordinary amount of help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to all a function that returns a Task you'd just do this:

```
var result = LoadDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Of course, this is not forcing the method to run synchronously, rather it is telling the compiler that you want to wait until the asynchronous task completes and then return the results. It is functionally equivalent to

```
var result = await LoadDataAsync();
```

All this syntax does is allow you to skip annotating your method with an async keyword. You *do* need to wait one way or the other. If you are calling a method that runs asynchronously and you need to do something to wait for that function to complete and return the data to you, otherwise you would get bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Just a point of caution, when you make a blocking call on an async method (either by Wait() or .Result) you have the risk of causing a dead lock if the SynchronizationContext of the calling method is not null. Because the async method will attempt to schedule its continuation on the Synchronization Context of the calling method but the calling method blocks on the completion of the async method so you end up in a dead lock.

One way to guarantee no dead lock is to push this async call to a background thread ie. by Task.Run. Background threads do not have SynchronizationContext so no dead lock.

Something like:

```
var result = Task.Run(async() => await LoadDataAsync()).Result;
```

ps. You do not need to call Wait() before the Result property. Result will block the thread until task is completed.